# Based on this data sheet for the 74HCT173, which section(s) describes the maximum current I can draw per output pin?

Tags: amperage, pins

I want to size the LED's with resistor in series properly.

Thanks

https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT173.pdf

Comment: Try reading what it says on page 6.

Comment: Actually the info is in **table 5** on page 5. Note that any current that flows into or out of an output also flows into / out of the supply and ground pins. You should not violate **any** of the stated maximum ratings. If you don't want to break the IC that is.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Table 5 doesn't tell you how much current you actually can get out of any pin, it just tells you what current level may damage the part. These are boilerplate maximum ratings.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I know and agree with your comment. However, there aren't any output current ratings specified so the max ratings are all we have. OK, Peter's answer uses the output voltage under load specs as a way around that. Expected conclusion: only if you want to drive your LEDs with only a few mA then it's OK to drive them directly from the IC's output. If you want for example 20 mA: use a MOSFET to switch the actual LED current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some considerations here.

**Maximum ratings.**

The *absolute maximum ratings* must not be exceeded (and you should not normally go anywhere near them).

For this device, they are:
[image: HC173 Max Ratings]

This shows that you *could* draw up to 35 mA from an output, but the total device current must not exceed 70 mA (so you could not draw this from all the outputs). In addition, you need to keep the device reasonably cool so you would want to keep the power dissipation down.

Now we can look at the output current vs. output voltage:

[image: hc173 outputs]

If I assume you are using the device with a 5 V supply and driving the outputs low to run your LEDs (not listed here so I will use the 4.5 V numbers), then if you draw 6 mA, at room temperature you will have an output voltage of between 16 mA and 26 mV.

That yields power in the output stage of 156 µW *per output* so the total would be 624 µW if all 4 were driven low at the same time.

Now 6 mA is usually quite sufficient for most LEDs in normal lighting.

If you want to drive a bit harder, then although the data sheet is silent on what the output voltage would be at 10 mA, we could estimate it. The output resistance of the bottom transistor is about $$\frac {26\ mV} {6\ mA} = 4.3\ \Omega.$$.

At an output current of 10 mA, there would be an output voltage of 43 mV for a power dissipation of 430 µW per output.

So it might be possible to drive 15 mA (total 60 mA if all outputs are active) which would yield about 640 µW per output; that would give a total current of 60 mA if all outputs were active which is within (but a bit close for my taste) the absolute maximum ratings. You will need to keep in mind that there are other currents that add to I<sub>cc</sub> (see 'additional supply current' on page 7).

Note that if the outputs are switching at any sort of fast rate you will need to add the power dissipated by switching (the calculation is on page 10 of the datasheet).

Comment: Your second table is for 74HC173 not for 74HCT173. Also "have an output voltage of between 16 and 26mV" should be 160 and 260mV.

Answer (score -1):

Based on this table you can draw a maximum of 35 mA per pin, up to 70 mA in total.
[image]

Comment: No, the table **does not** say that you can (are able to) draw 35mA from any particular pin at any particular voltage. The table says that currents above these levels may damage the device, but there is no guarantee whatsoever that these currents are actually available.

Comment: You are right, table lists maximal values and current is not guaranteed. However there is no better reference regarding maximal output current in the datasheet.